# What would be a good way to pivot this data?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have data in the following granularity:

```
CityID | Name | Post_Science | Post_Science | Post_Reading | Pre_Reading | Post_Writing | Pre_Writing  
123    | Bob  | 2.0          | 1.0          |     2.0      |    4.0      |     1.0      | 1.0
```

I'll be calling those `<Post/Pre>_XXXXXX` columns as Labels. Basically, these column names without the 'Pre' or 'Post' text map to a Label in another table.

I want to pivot the data in a way so that the `pre` and `post` values of the same Label are in the same row, for each group of `CityID, Name, Label`. So it would look like this:

```
CityID | Name | Pre Category | Post Category | Label 
123    | Bob  | 1.0          |     2.0       | Science
123    | Bob  | 4.0          |     2.0       | Reading
123    | Bob  | 1.0          |     1.0       | Writing
```

The `Label` comes from a separate table via a join. Hopefully that doesn't confuse anyone. If it does, ignore the column for now.

So there are much more of these categories - Science, Reading, and Writing are just a few I picked for example.

I've thought of two options to get the data in this format:

1. Unpivot all the data into a long list of all the values at a group of `CityID, Name, Label`. Then parse the Label name and pivot back into the pre and post values of one category into 1 row
2. Do a bunch of `Union`s. So select all Science in one `select` statement, all the `Reading` in another select statement and union them. There are about 50 pairings, so 50 union statements

I'm imagining the first option is cleaner than the latter. Any other options though?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is *unpivoting* and I strongly recommend `apply`:

```
select t.CityId, t.Name, v.*
from t cross apply
     (values (t.Post_Science, t.Pre_Science, 'Science'),
             (t.Post_Reading, t.Pre_Reading, 'Reading'),
             (t.Post_Writing, t.Pre_Writing, 'Writing')
     ) v(postcategory, precategory, label) ;
```

`UNPIVOT` is very particular syntax to do one thing.  `APPLY` introduces lateral joins, which are very powerful for this and many other purposes.

Answer (score 2):

Clearly Gordon's solution would be more performant, but if you have **MANY or VARIABLE COLUMNS**, here is an option that will dynamically UNPIVOT your data without actually using DYNAMIC SQL

**Example**

```
Select A.CityID
      ,A.Name
      ,PreCat  = max(case when Item Like 'Pre%'  then Value end)
      ,PostCat = max(case when Item Like 'Post%' then Value end)
      ,Label   = substring(Item,charindex('_',Item+'_')+1,50)
 From  YourTable A
 Cross Apply ( values (cast((Select A.* for XML RAW) as xml))) B(XMLData)
 Cross Apply (
                Select Item  = xAttr.value('local-name(.)', 'varchar(100)')
                      ,Value = xAttr.value('.','varchar(max)')
                 From  XMLData.nodes('//@*') xNode(xAttr)
                 Where xAttr.value('local-name(.)','varchar(100)') not in ('CityId','Name','Other-Columns','To-Exclude')
             ) C
 Group By A.CityID
         ,A.Name
         ,substring(Item,charindex('_',Item+'_')+1,50)
```

**Returns**

```
CityID  Name    PreCat  PostCat Label
123     Bob     4.0     2.0     Reading
123     Bob     1.0     2.0     Science
123     Bob     1.0     1.0     Writing
```